# Good way to present wireframes to stakeholder for application concept?

Tags: interaction-design, information-architecture, ux-field, feedback, design-process

For a lesson-making application, I have designed wireframes with multiple user flows to help illustrate the important features within the application (i.e user creates a lesson , user clicks and drags something, etc). However, I was wondering if there were alternatives that could be more effective in presenting my wireframes. For more context, this stakeholder has a strong opinion, and basically said "Design this".

If I were to go with presenting user flows, would it be better to present individual stories for each flow/design concept, or present the same story for the different flows? Also, when soliciting feedback, would it be better to present everything or ask for feedback after each flow?

Regarding alternatives, would showing a more "final" part of the user flow be effective? (For example, presenting wireframes of an interface with many lessons and quizzes already created).

Thanks and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Who is the stakeholder - a mid-manager, a business owner, an investor? Successful presentation depends on the stakeholder's insight into their customers and that may vary greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the scope or the resources you might have for the concept, but when I present an idea to a stakeholder I always put together a quick prototype (in Figma, or more recently in Protopie). This enables you to "show, not tell" and stakeholders get a better understanding of the ideas presented.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when it comes to showcasing the solution, always keep in mind that they are less aware with the flow, connecting links and all. so just sharing the link with all the wireframes static wont work and they wont even be more interested into seeing this. even its wireframe, make it in clickable prototype form, either share the prototype link with all the hotspots where click would work or you can record the video prototype and share it in video format. this way you can share your ideas or thoughts effectively.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to start by stating the problems you found.

This helps your stakeholders dive into the context.

And the last tip is to craft a story for each use case (so you can leverage empathy).